# Array of object's index from request attribute in jsp and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

Is it possible to:

**1**

When I do:

```
$('#NContrato' ).val('${personList[0].NContrato}');
```

It works. But if I do

```
$('#NContrato' ).val('${personList[' + ind + '].NContrato}');
$('#NContrato' ).val('${personList[ind].NContrato}');
$('#NContrato' ).val('${personList[${ind}].NContrato}');
```

It doesn't and this is request.setAttribute(personList, ...) in a controller (I'm using spring MVC)

```
$('#NContrato' + ind)  // JQuery $() ...It works but
${'${personList[' + ind ...}  //Request ${} doesn't work concatenating string's
${personList[0].NContrato} // Works
```

Is there a way to do it?

**2**

I'd like to change 
newPerson to have the clone of
${personList[0]}

I tried this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setNewPerson(ind) {
${newPerson=personList[0]};
}
</script>
```

but .... it gives this error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/t4imovelZMAguaEdpGass.jsp(153,3) PWC6038: 
"${newPerson=personList[0]}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: 
Error Parsing: "${newPerson=personList[0]}"

**EDIT:**

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach items="${personList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
  .....
<button type="button"  onclick="change(${item.id},${status.count})"></button> 
.....                       
</c:forEach>
     .....  

<form:form action="save()"  method="post" modelAttribute="newPerson" id="personId" >
....
<form:input path="NContrato" id="NContrato" />
 ....
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(id, ind) {
        $('#NContrato' ).val('${personList[0].NContrato}'); //Works

        var ind=0;
        $('#NContrato' ).val("${'personList[' + ind + '].NContrato'}"); // <- 1 Question    
        ....

        ${newPerson=personList[0]}; // <- 2 Question    
    }
</script>
```

**Controller (Servlet)**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saves*", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("newPerson") Person person,                                                              
    BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ...
    request.setAttribute("newPerson", subForm);
    ...
    request.setAttribute("personList", personManager.getPersonList())
    ....
    return new ModelAndView( "personJSP");
}
```

Comment: You're confusing some basic web development concepts. Server side languages like Java/JSP/Servlet runs in webserver listening on HTTP requests and generates HTML/CSS/JS output as HTTP responses. Client side languages like HTML/CSS/JS get executed by webbrowser itself once the entire HTTP response is arrived. Java/JSP/Servlet and HTML/CSS/JS doesn't run in sync. HTML/CSS/JS is merely "template text" which Java/JSP/Servlet has to produce. Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Do you see it now? There's no single line of Java/JSP/Servlet code in there!

Comment: @BalusC thanks for your answer. Could you see my edit? Any help?

Comment: `${'${personList[' + ind ...}` - you cannot do it this way. You are mixing Java and JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you start coding JSP using EL without first learning the basics, the original old way of doing things, you will be forever confused. EL's ${} looks kind of like jquery's $() operator, but it is not.

The EL expression

```
${personList[0].NContrato}
```

is equivalent to

```
<%= personList[0].NContrato %>
```

or

```
<%   out.print( personList[0].NContrato ); %>
```

It runs on the server side and prints the value of personList[0].NContrato into the HTML source you are building.

The expression

```
 ${personList[' + ind + '].NContrato}
```

does nothing.  Why?  Because ${} runs on the server and only prints variables.  There is no variable named "personList[' + ind + '].NContrato".  That exact text "${personList[' + ind + '].NContrato}" will be printed into your HTML source.  Hence the importance of viewing the source in the browser when troubleshooting.

As for

```
${newPerson=personList[0]};
```

you can't do an assignment like that in EL. Ask yourself if the following would make any sense at all?

```
 <% out.print( newPerson=personList[0] ); %>
```

It doesn't make sense to do an assignment inside a print command.

Comment: thanks @developerwjk! I know ${} EL runs on server side ... but I'd like to access it in JS, not to make an ajax call :-) ...  There is no way to print personList['var'].NContrato ? Where can I learn more of EL? here? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: Essentially to make your Java list object available to Javascript you have to copy it over to the client side somehow. Either (1) via an Ajax call or (2) by printing the entire list into a Javascript array in the JSP in question. Or (3) by putting the list into a cookie.  Those are the 3 options you have.